# Probability to develop a new type of melanoma

Tags: dermatology, cancer, risks, melanoma, moles

I saw that there are [different types of melanoma](https://cancer.ca/en/cancer-information/cancer-types/skin-melanoma/what-is-melanoma/types-of-melanoma): some are more aggressive and others are less dangerous. From what I understood searching on web, the causes of melanoma are not clear but there are factors that may increase the risk like UV light exposure, light skin and genetic predisposition factors.

If one patient has already got a certain type of melanoma in his/her life, there is a higher probability that he/she could develop an other melanoma with respect to someone that has never had one. It is reported in [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3076705/) research paper by Dr Porcia T. Bradford et al.:

> Melanoma survivors have an approximately 9-fold increased risk of developing subsequent melanoma compared with the general population.

My doubt is: should one consider a higher probability to develop the same type of melanoma already had in the past or a higher probability to develop a new melanoma that can be of all the types? For example: if one has already had a superficial spreading melanoma, is the probability to develop a new superficial spreading melanoma equal to the probability of developing a nodular melanoma (which is more dangerous) ?

Since the causes or, better, the risk factors seem to be the same, I would answer yes to my question. What do you think?

Thank you in advance.